# how to fix cannot resolve symbol and variable never used, errors

Tags: java

I am new to java and this is my first program, I'm very confused with these errors and have looked everywhere for the answer. please help!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter first number");
        String str1 = myObj.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter Operator");
        String op = myObj.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Enter second number");
        String str2 = myObj.nextLine();

        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(str1);
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(str2);

        if (op.equals("+")) {
            int ans = (num1 + num2);
        } else if (op.equals("-")){
            int ans = (num1 - num2);
        }
        System.out.println(num1 + " " + op + " " + num2 + " = " + ans);
    }
}
```

Then it gives me these errors, I'm using IntelliJ idea

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'ans'
Variable 'ans' is never used
Variable 'ans' is never used
```

Comment: Declare `ans` _before_ the `if-else` statement. Currently, there are two `ans` variables declared in your code and their access is limited to the block in which they are declared.

Comment: Just to add to @Yousaf comment. A block is the {} brackets. So when you declare a ans inside the block the code outside the block doesn't know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cannot resolve symbol 'ans'

Declare `ans` outside the if:

```
    int ans = 0; 
    if (op.equals("+")) {
        ans = (num1 + num2);
    } else if (op.equals("-")){
        ans = (num1 - num2);
    }
    System.out.println(num1 + " " + op + " " + num2 + " = " + ans);
```

otherwise it is never visible in the line where it is used in `System.out.println`

> Variable 'ans' is never used
>
> Variable 'ans' is never used

In your code `ans` is declared in the if - code blocks, and after assignment those `ans` are no longer used, because code-block in if  ends just after the assignment.

Comment: I did that but then it gave me this error: Variable ans is already defined in method main

Comment: @JacksonLong you need to change `int ans = (num1 + num2);` to `ans = (num1 + num2);`; do the same thing in the `else` block.